# iterate through csv columns to create multiple python dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create multiple data frames using the columns of a excel csv file.  This is where I have been able to get to

```html
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(file)
cols = df.columns
#column names are 'Date', 'Stock 1', 'Stock 2', etc - I have 1000 columns

for i in range(len(cols)):
    df[i] = df[['Date',b(i)]]
```

So the end result is I want multiple dataframes.  The first dataframe is with columns 1 and 2 (so Date and Stock 1), the second dataframe is with columns 1 and 3 (so Date and Stock 2), the third dataframe is with columns 1 and 3, creating new dataframe all the way to Columns 1 and 1000.

I have tried several ways and either get index in not callable or I tried with usecols and I get usecols must be strings or integers.

Can anyone help me with this.  Conceptually it is easy but I can not get the code right.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you are asking:

```
all_dfs = []
for col in df.columns:
    if col != 'Date':
        df_current = df[['Date', col]]
        all_dfs.append(df_current)
```

Or as one line:

```
all_dfs = [df[['Date', col]] for col in df.columns if col != 'Date']
```

But you probably don't want to do that. There's not much point. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: You might need to have an if statement for `col != 'Date'`

Comment: I am ultimately trying to create multiple data dataframes with Date and 1 column from the CSV.  THe CSV has 1000 columns all with a stock and column of stock prices

Header 1    Header 2    Header 3    Header 4
========    ========    ========    ========
Date         Stock 1    Stock 2     Stock 3
1/2/2001     2.77        6.00        11.00 
1/3/2001     2.89         6.08       11.10 
1/4/2001     2.86         6.33       11.97 
1/5/2001     2.80         6.58       12.40

Comment: so I ultimately want to produce 100 dataframes so DF1 would be Date and Stock 1 and DF2 would be Date and Stock2, etc.

Comment: Did you try @bananafish's solution? `all_dfs` should return the list of dfs you need with *Date* and *Stock*. In fact, it is better to keep as one list object instead of 100s of dfs flooding global environment (especially if same structure). Just reference each by index: `all_dfs[1]`.

Comment: @JWestwood right, but what are you going to do with these dataframes? Most likely you can do it without creating 100s of dataframes in the first place and just sticking with the one you are loading from the csv.

Comment: @banafish.  This solution worked.  After I have all DFs I have more code that adds more columns to each DF. So moving averages based on price and then calculates return based on signals from multiple columns.  i went about this approach because I can visualize each dataframe as seperate entities but I am new to this and if thats incorrect approach or if there is a faster way to accomplish it let me know.  with 1000 columns (dfs) and I am adding 20 more calculation columns to each dataframe speed will be important