# Add multiple columns to multiple data frames

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

I have a number of number of small dataframes with a date and stock price for a given stock.  [Someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41233810/1422451) showed me how to loop through them so they are contained in a list called *all_dfs*.  So `all_dfs[0]` would be a dataframe with *Date* and *IBM US equity*, `all_dfs[1]` would be *Date* and *MMM US Equity*, etc.  (example shown below).  The *Date* column in the dataframes is always the same but the stock names are all different and the numbers associated with that stock column are always different.  So when you call `all_dfs[1]` this is the dataframe you would see (i.e., `all_dfs[1].head()`):

```
IDX       Date          MMM US equity    
0         1/3/2000      47.19    
1         1/4/2000      45.31    
2         1/5/2000      46.63    
3         1/6/2000      50.38
```

I want to add the same additional columns to EVERY dataframe.  So I was trying to loop through them and add the columns.  The numbers in the stock name columns are the basis for the calculations that make the other columns.

There are more columns to add but I think they will all loop through the same way soc this is a sample of the columns I want to add:

```
Column 1 to add >>> df['P_CHG1D'] = df['Stock name #1'].pct_change(1) * 100

Column 2 to add >>> df['PCHG_SIG'] = P_CHG1D > 3

Column 3 to add>>> df['PCHG_SIG']= df['PCHG_SIG'].map({True:1,False:0})
```

This is the code that I have so far but it is returning a syntax errors for the `all_dfs[i]`.

```
for i in range (len(df.columns)):
for all_dfs[i]: 
    df['P_CHG1D']  = df.loc[:,0].pct_change(1) * 100
```

So I also have 2 problems that I can not figure out

1. I dont know how to add columns to every dataframes in the loop.  So I would have to do something like `all_dfs[i].['ADD COLUMN NAME'] = df['Stock Name 1'].pct_change(1) * 100`
2. the second part after the =  which is the `df['Stock Name 1']` this keeps changing (so in this example it is called *MMM US Equity* but the next time it would be called the column header of the second dataframe - so it could be *IBM US Equity*) as each dataframe has a different name so I don't know how to call that properly in the loop

I am new to python/pandas so if I am thinking about this the wrong way let me know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider iterating through the length of *alldfs* to reference each element in loop by its index. For first new column, use `.ix` operator to select stock column by its column position of 2 (third column):

```
for i in range(len(alldfs)):
    dfList[i].is_copy = False   # TURNS OFF SettingWithCopyWarning

    dfList[i]['P_CHG1D'] = dfList[i].ix[:, 2].pct_change(1) * 100
    dfList[i]['PCHG_SIG'] = dfList[i]['P_CHG1D'] > 3
    dfList[i]['PCHG_SIG_VAL'] = dfList[i]['PCHG_SIG'].map({True:1,False:0})
```

Comment: This works but it does provide an error as follows
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'

Any idea what this means >> but even with the error the dataframes compile with the right information.  So I am not sure what this is telling me

Comment: Is *Stock* your third or second column in each df? Per your posted, data, I am assuming stock is third column. But this suggests, *Date* is being used as its separator `/` shows in error. Maybe some dfs have *Date* as third col? Add `print(i)` to find which df in list is the problem.